# Is there anyway to round out the the corners of a shape layer without using 'Stroke' or a 'Layer Mask'?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

Is there anyway to round out the the corners of a shape layer without using 'Stroke' or a 'Layer Mask'?

I tried converting the text layer into a shape layer and seeing if photoshop would allow me to use the 'Corner Radius' setting on them with no luck.

Comment: .. properties panel....

Comment: There is no option in the 'Properties' panel to do so. THAT is why I asked.

Comment: Are you *certain* it's a shape layer.. and what version of Photoshop? In Photoshop CC there should be [corner options in the properties panel](https://creativepro.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/default/files/20140305-cornerps-4.png) for a shape layer. If you aren't seeing this, then there's something else at play.

Comment: If the shape is a non-standard shape.. then any rounding has to be done *manually*. Automated corner rounding is reserved for standard, default, rectangles.

Comment: No  answer, but a workaround. Copy and paste the shape to Illustrator. Edit, for ex. insert  corner rounding or other effects. Copy and paste it back as a shape layer when it's right. Or make it in Illustrator from the start. It can be pasted to Photoshop as pixels, smart object, path or shape.